Set default priority for all the alerts of a service in PagerDuty
I am trying to set a default priority per service.
For instance, we have some business services that are critical. And any alerts coming from it should be of priority P1.
In comparison, some other services are less critical, and we would like to have a lower priority for all alerts, like P3.
As of now, it seems there is no default priority.

I tried to set some keywords in the alert, like tagging the alert title with P1, P3, etc., hoping pager duty would pick it up, but no luck.
[
  {
    "key": "priority",
    "value": "P4"
  },
  {
    "key": "env",
    "value": "global"
  },
  {
    "key": "service",
    "value": "my-P4-service"
  }
]


Title of the alert would be like this: P4 some description
How to set up one default priority for all alerts coming from a particular service?
